# Is there a good example of a paper chess book converted to an ebook?

Tags: books

With Epub, or other ebook formats, one can take advantage of the format and do things that are difficult to do in a paper book. Hyperlinking, extra diagrams, more page breaks - what else? Most books for kindle I can find on amazon have been "converted" from paper books, but have identical content to their paper counterparts. Is there a good example of a popular/good chess book that is much easier to study on electronic device?

Comment: By electronic device - I mostly refer to a reader such as kindle, capable of consuming epub (with conversion if necessary). I am making the assumption that the user is not going to deal with installing separate app for reading pgn files (and no current app on a mobile device is able to load cbh files AFAIK)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by an "electronic device", but there has been ebook versions of chess books for quite some time, from publishers like [Everyman](http://www.everymanchess.com/catsearch.php?area=ebook), although admittedly these are nothing like regular ebooks. Of course your device must be capable of running CB reader or an equivalent that can open the chessbase format files.

On the more practical side of things, chess books don't sell very well and formatting even the printed copy is a lot of work. QualityChess has [no intention](http://www.qualitychess.co.uk/docs/13/faq/) of producing ebooks that can be easily copied:

> Q: Will your books be available as pgn or ChessBase e-books?
>
> A: As long as it is easy to copy these forms of readers, it makes absolutely no sense. Why other companies choose to do this is a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

There are also good examples of electronic chess books like Forward Chess for iOS that has books already converted to interactive format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of any special epub books.  The problem with epub is that you can't move the pieces on the boards.

Most chess book publishers seem to be going with separate apps: Everyman's Chess Viewer reads their pgn books, and the rest use proprietary formats that display a chess board where you can play through the game by clicking on the notation or arrows: e+chess/New In Chess Books and Files (iOS only?), Gambit Publications' Chess Studio, Forward Chess (Quality Chess, New In Chess, Informant, Chess Stars), Chessapps, MChess and Smartchess.  Chessapps and Smartchess give you access to an engine for analyzing the positions.  Chessapps also lets you save your notes.

I haven't tried it, but there is an app called 'Cbh to pgn' for converting on Android.